# AJAX call using IIFE? Can't seem to get .done to work the same as a regular function

Tags: javascript, ajax, iife

I currently have an AJAX call out to a PHP file that works, that is the following:

```
//Load map from database
function getMap(){
    return $.ajax({
    url: "getMap.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    });
};
getMap().done(function(r) {
    if (r) {
        loadedMap(JSON.parse(r.mapArray), JSON.parse(r.mapProperties)); //call     loadedMap(r) if loading a map from DB
    } else {
       console.log("No data");
    }
}).fail(function(x) {
   console.log("error");
});
```

That works within a single javascript file that successfully passes r.mapArray and r.mapProperties to my main loadedMap function.

I'm trying to learn about the IIFE Javascript Module model, and split my work up into separate files.

So, I currently have main.js:

```
(function() {
  // let's get our map
  var gameMap = mapGen.getMap().done();
  console.log(gameMap);
})();
```

and mapGen.js:

```
var mapGen = function() {  
   return {
      getMap: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "getMap.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'JSON',
        });
      }
   };
}()
```

If I console.log(gameMap), I see the responseText JSON object with my data. I just can't seem to access it.  console.log(gameMap.responseText) is undefined. as is gameMap.responseJSON (though I see both of them in the console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking the code over it looks as the the separation of the files was not the issue and that looks to be implemented correctly. The issue is with how you are handling the AJAX request. The function mapGen.getMap() actually returns a jqXHR Object as opposed to the response that you are trying to access.

Just as you had in your previous file, you will need handle the response of your request.

```
(function() {
  // let's get our map request
  var gameMap = mapGen.getMap();
  gameMap.done(function(r){ ... }).
  fail(function(x){ ... });
})();
```

You will be able to access the response data you are looking for within the done() function.

Comment: You have an extra ) after function(r) but that does the trick! 

So, my main question would be: If my goal is to separate functionality into different JS files, but all the JS files, and the function within, require access to that AJAX data... I'll need to call mapGen.getMap every time, so I could feed any function I needed with the parameter of the AJAX data.

Hmm.  Seems hard to separate functionality if you need a global data object.

I appreciate the answer. I thought this was going to get lost due to the time it was out with no comments.

Comment: I made an edit to fix that extra paren. To achieve what you are looking for you could break this up into two operations: an `initMap(callback)` and a `getMap()`. initMap would then store the result of your AJAX request and can execute the callback so your code now has the map data. A jsfiddle of the example. Note: the AJAX call will error since it doesn't have a correct path. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fDL7/)